# Testing communication between Watch Extension and iPhone app in background mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, background

I [have added a background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693786/adding-background-mode-on-capabilities-tabs/29693831#29693831) execution mode on my iPhone app. I added a WatchKit extension to my project and now I started testing the communication between the two using [Xcode simulators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677132/understanding-handlewatchkitextensionrequest).

It works fine when the iPhone app is in **foreground**. However when I press the home button and the iPhone app goes in **background** the breakpoint that I added on **handleWatchKitExtensionRequest** (in AppDelegate.m) won't work anymore (it works when the app is in foreground).

Does this mean that the **iPhone app is not executing in background**?

**Purpose:**

- I need the to be able to get updates from the BLE devices and send them to the Watch even if the app is in background.

Comment: is your app received event while goes in background?

Comment: may [Enable Background Mode For BLE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669156/how-to-add-background-infinite-timer-with-background-mode-ble-central-in-ios/29713399#29713399) help you.